# Only USERID, PID, TIME, and COMMAND for specific user Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have to get Only USERID, PID, TIME, and COMMAND for a specific user. I have tried

```
ps -u user1
```

But that display 
`PID TTY TIME CMD`, but I dont want the Field TTY. 
Can any one help me to find the USERID, PID, TIME, and COMMAND of a specific user

Comment: I think this question might be better suited to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ps` option `-o` to specify the output with `uid,pid,time,cmd`

```
ps -u user1 -o uid,pid,time,cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get the required details

```
# ps -e -o pid,time,cmd,user | sed 1q; ps -e -o pid,time,cmd,user | grep '[u]ser_name'
```

replace username with your user. For example, alen would be '[a]len'